# How can I delete spesific data in a txt file (PHP)

Tags: php

I want to delete spesific data from a txt file. My example txt file is below. I want to delete between `<!--something-->` and `<!--#something-->`. (include these html codes). How can I do this in PHP?

My example txt file:

```
etc. etc. etc.
<!--something-->
here is data what I want to delete.
<!--#something-->
etc. etc. et.
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: [LMGTFY](http://www.google.com)

Comment: 1) write code 2) test code 3) execute code

Comment: @MarcB You left out 4) pray it won't go boom.

Comment: Hint: Use regular expressions or parse the content as HTML and delete the comment nodes.

Comment: I can't do it, because of this, I write here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
$newFile = '';
$skipp = false;
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if( stristr($line,'<!--something-->') !== false ) {
            $skipp = true;
        }
        if(!$skipp){
            $newFile .= $line;
        }
        if( stristr($line,'<!--#something-->') !== false ) {
            $skipp = false;
        }

    }

    fclose($handle);
}
//file_put_contents("inputfile.txt",$newFile)
echo $newFile;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But I want to ask this: how can I also delete <!--autologout--> ?? If you'll help me, then I'll be happy, if not, no problem bro thanks!

Comment: Is it the same as <!--something--> where it has a opening and a closing <!--# like that

Comment: Sorry I asked wrongly, how can I delete <!--#something-->. Because this part of the code wasn't deleted.

Comment: Move if(!$skipp){...} part up above if( stristr($line,'<!--#something-->') !== false ){...} i edited the code above